# React's TestUtils.Simulate.keyDown does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, karma-runner

I have a lot of components in my application that respond to different key presses, and so far, none of my tests that use `TestUtils.Simulate.keyDown` work at all.  It seems like `keyDown` just plain and simple does not work.

Here's the component I'm trying to test:

#### description.js

```
var React = require('react/addons');

var Description = React.createClass({
    render : function () {
        return (
            <div className="description">
                <input type="text" ref="input"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = Description;
```

And here is a simple test that is failing:

#### description-test.js

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
var expect = require('expect');
var Description = require('../description');

describe('Description', function () {
    it('updates input value on key press', function () {
        var description = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Description/>);
        var input = React.findDOMNode(description.refs.input);
        expect(input.value).toEqual(''); //This passes
        TestUtils.Simulate.keyDown(input, {key : "a"});
        expect(input.value).toEqual('a'); //This fails
    });
});
```

I have multiple tests that rely on `TestUtils.Simulate.keyDown`.  These tests try a multitude of different keys to press (with Enter being the most prominent), but none of them work.  I've tried using `keyPress` and `keyUp`, not knowing if those functions even exist at all (shoutout to the surprisingly incomplete documentation).

Am I just using the function incorrectly?  Or is there something else wrong here?

I'm using karma-cli via npm to run my tests, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up figuring out the issue.

```
TestUtils.Simulate.keyDown(input, {key : "a"});
```

This line sends an event to the correct DOM node, but the event data doesn't actually contain a `keyCode`, which is what the code is looking for.  Why the official documentation specifically says you should use `key` is beyond me.

For it to function correctly, the following modification needed to be made:

```
TestUtils.Simulate.keyDown(input, {keyCode : 65});
```

I hope this helps out someone else with a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

`TestUtils.Simulate` does not actually change values, but rather simulates events on the targeted elements. So if you had an `onKeyDown` handler on your `input`, simulating `keyDown` with `TestUtils` would let you see if that handler works correctly.

To change the value of the `input` you can try changing it directly with `this.refs.input.value = 'a'`, or simulate a change event if you have an `onChange` handler that you want to test:

```
TestUtils.Simulate.change(input, { target: { value: 'a' } })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This component actually does have an `onKeyDown` handler that I stripped from the original question for simplicity.  The handler looks for users pressing Enter and Backspace, and while the component functions correctly on the page, the tests for this handler did not function correctly.

Comment: Okay @MichaelParker, well, in any event it is correct that `input.value` does not equal `'a'` after simulating a `keyDown`. If you can't simulate enter/backspace effectively with `TestUtils` you may want to change your example code/tests above and we can go from there.

Comment: I actually figured out the issue, see my answer.  I appreciate the response though :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I had a very similar problem from a SearchInput component that send the text introduced when hitting enter. 
I had some tests as follows:

```
describe('SearchInput functionality,', () => {
  let mockData, component, input;

  beforeAll(() => {
    mockData = {
      searchCriteria: "something",
      emptyString: "       ",
      submitHandler: function(filter) {
        // storing filter param in mockData, it means SearchInput called handler successfully
        mockData.filter = filter;
      }
    };

    spyOn(mockData, 'submitHandler').and.callThrough();

    component = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <SearchInput placeholder="Search..." onSubmit={mockData.submitHandler}/>
    );
    input = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(component, 'input');
  });

  it('user writes a search criteria and hits enter', () => {
    input.value = mockData.searchCriteria;
    ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change(input);
    ReactTestUtils.Simulate.keyDown(input, {key: "Enter", keyCode: 13, which: 13});

    expect(mockData.filter).toEqual(mockData.searchCriteria);
    expect(mockData.submitHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockData.submitHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

And it didn't work.

But after some research I changed the **keyDown** by **keyPress** and everything worked perfectly. The reason, enter key was never actually pressed, then input value was never sent and all the assertions failed.