# Simulate keydown on document for JEST unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, addeventlistener, jestjs, reactjs-testutils

Using `JEST` to unit test a component that has a keydown listener attached to the document.

How can I test this in `JEST`? How do I simulate the keydown event on the document? I need the event listener to be on the document since it is supposed to respond the keyboard action irrespective of the focussed element.

EDIT: The question here is about simulating the event on the document or the document.body. All the examples are regarding an actual DOM node, that works fine but the document does not.

Currently trying to do this:

```
TestUtils.Simulate.keyDown(document, {keyCode : 37}); // handler not invoked
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React's TestUtils.Simulate.keyDown does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628093/reacts-testutils-simulate-keydown-does-not-work)

Answer (score 46):

I had the exact same problem and unfortunately couldn't find any details on how to solve this using `TestUtils.Simulate`. However [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5043) gave me the idea of simply calling `.dispatchEvent` with a `KeyboardEvent` inside my jest tests directly:

```
var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'keyCode': 37});
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

You can find details on the `KeyboardEvent` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

Comment: For me it only worked when changing `'keydown'` to `'keypress'`

Comment: As of 2020 and latest version of Jest, this works for me if I use `global.dispatchEvent` instead of `window.dispatchEvent`

Comment: In addition, you may need `bubbles: true` in the event data.

Answer (score 4):

You can also replace the whole `document.eventListener` with mock function before you mount the component:

```
let events;
document.addEventListener = jest.fn((event, cb) => {
  events[event] = cb;
});
```

And simulate event by calling `events[event]` after mounting, e.g.:

```
events.keydown({ keyCode: 37 })
```

Also, it's quite comfortable to do first part in `beforeEach()` function if you have many tests dealing with DOM events.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Iris Schaffer answer,
If your code makes use of `ctrl/alt/shift` keys, you will need to init them, as well as mocking implementation of `getModifierState` method on `KeyboardEvent`

```
const keyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { keyCode, shiftKey, altKey, ctrlKey });
jest.spyOn(keyboardEvent, 'getModifierState').mockImplementation((modifier) => {
     switch (modifier) {
          case 'Alt':
               return altKey;
          case 'Control':
               return ctrlKey;
          case 'Shift':
               return shiftKey;
     }
});
```