# How to get line coverage on React.useEffect hook when using Jest and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

Using React, enzyme and jest, How can I get code coverage on my `closeDrawer()` callback prop inside `useEffect()`

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {Button} from './button';

const DrawerClose = ({closeDrawer}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleEsc = (e: any) => {
      if (e.key === 'Escape') {
        closeDrawer();
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('keyup', handleEsc);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('keyup', handleEsc);
  });
  return (
    <Button>
      close
    </Button>
  );
};

export {DrawerClose};
```

Test:

```
import React from 'react';
import {DrawerClose as Block} from './drawer-close';

describe(`${Block.name}`, () => {
  it('should have drawer open', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Block closeDrawer={() => 'closed'} />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot(); // will not hit the useEffect
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shallow()` does not call `useEffect` yet. It's [known issue #2086](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2086) and happens because of React's shallow renderer.

You can either use `mount()` and render completely or mock every/some nested component and still use `mount()` but having results more like `shallow()` could. Something like:

```
jest.mock('../../Button.jsx', (props) => <span {...props} />);
```

As for testing itself you need to ensure that `closeDrawer` will be called on hitting ESC. So we need to use spy and simulate simulate hitting ESC

```
const closeDrawerSpy = jest.fn();
const wrapper = mount(<Block closeDrawer={closeDrawerSpy} />);
// simulate ESC pressing
```

As for simulating ESC pressed on window, I'm not sure if jest-dom allows, you may try(taken from [Simulate keydown on document for JEST unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638385/simulate-keydown-on-document-for-jest-unit-testing))

```
var event = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {'keyCode': 27});
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

If that does not work(`window.dispatchEvent is not a function` or something alike) you always [can mock `addEventListener`](https://medium.com/@DavideRama/testing-global-event-listener-within-a-react-component-b9d661e59953) to have direct access to handlers.