# How do I dispatch multiple dispatch keypress events in javascript(jest testing)?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, keypress, keydown

Expectations:

I want to dispatch multiple keypress events simutamusly. For example, I want my test to simulate a shift+tab event with

The code :

```
...
describe("ESC press", () => {

// How do i use this dispatch event to simulate a key press of shift+tab 

    document.dispatchEvent(escapeEvent)
    });
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34979556/19330634) twice to simulate multiple hold key events :

```
const shift = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'keyCode': 16});
document.dispatchEvent(event);

const tab = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'keyCode': 9});
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Cheers